# Why IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

The following code is used to find key points of an image given the location x y coordinates with variable "locs".tp=256,r=180,c=240. During debugging I am receiving an Index error for the line  ***desc[idx-1, ] = tmp***.

```
tp = compareX.shape[0]
desc = np.zeros((1, tp))
r = im.shape[0]
c = im.shape[1]
idx = 1
new_locs = np.zeros((locs.shape))


for i in range(1, locs.shape[0]):

    x = math.floor(locs[i - 1, 0])  # keypoint x coordinate
    y = math.floor(locs[i - 1, 1])  # keypoint y coordinate
    #non-maximum suppression 
    if (x - 4) < 1 or (y - 4) < 1 or (x + 4) > c or (y + 4) > r:
        continue

    #save passing coordinates
    new_locs[idx - 1,] = np.array([x, y])

    #Calculate BRIEF descriptor 
    tmp = np.zeros((1, tp))

    x = x-4
    y = y-4
    for j in range(1, tp):
        ax = x + math.floor((compareX[j-1]-1)/patchWidth)
        ay = y + ((compareX[j-1]-1) % patchWidth)
        bx = x + math.floor((compareY[j-1] - 1) / patchWidth)
        by = y + ((compareY[j-1] - 1) % patchWidth)
        if (im[ay, ax] < im[by, bx]).all():
            tmp[0, j-1] = 1
    ***desc[idx-1, ] = tmp***
    idx = idx + 1
locs = new_locs
return locs, desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up `desc` as having dimensions `1`x`tp` (think of it as 1 row, `tp` columns).

```
tp = 5

desc = np.zeros((1, tp))
# array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

desc.shape 
# (1, 5)
```

With zero-indexing, that means that referencing `desc[1, ]` is asking for row 2, when there is only one row in axis 0 (the row axis).
That's why you get the error: when `idx == 2`, then `desc[idx-1, ] == desc[1, ]`.
Maybe you want to index into axis 1 instead?  E.g. `desc[ ,1]`